# django 2.1 environment with venv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have a problem with the environment variables and django, I am following all the internet documentation but I can not find the problem, I did these steps

```
mkdir protectora.com
```

inside protectora.com

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 venv3.6
source venv3.6/bin/active
pip install django==2.1
django-admin startproject refugio
```

inside refugio

```
django-admin startapp polls
```

[image]
Now there's the problem, polls does not work if I do not install it as refugio.polls
[image]

```
'DIRS': os.path.join(BASEDIR,'refugio/templates')
```

it should not work this way, it seems that it is pointing out of shelter in the folder where manager.py is located

I also did another test

```
pip install gunicorn
```

in refugio

```
gunicorn wsgi:application
```

error:
[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the whole error? The beginning of the error might be useful. And maybe do it as text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You add `"refugio"` to installed apps as well.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'refugio',
    'refugio.polls',
    # other apps
]
```